# Using Outlook 2010 Custom Views

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, sorting, viewer

I frequently switch between emails sorted by date (newest on top), sorted by From, and sorted by conversation (oldest on top). I'm tired of right clicking and sorting my emails, especially with conversations; with conversations it always pops up "Show messages arranged by conversations in" dialog, which I never want to see, I always only want only that folder (a never show this message again dialog box would be great). In addition to this, Outlook never remembers my Use Classic Indented View setting and I always have to manually disable it. I thought that views would be the solution/workaround, but if I create a custom view, use the view, then change the sort order manually, it saves the manual change to the view, and Outlook doesn't allow me to reset the view. I don't want it to save the manual sorting change to the view, or as alternative I want to be able to reset the view, I'm not able to do either. Is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: wow, that is ridiculous.

Answer (score 2):

I found a good fix/work around for this issue: don't manually change the settings of a custom view. For example, when a Custom View is applied, do not re-sort by Date or From, and do not enable or disable the conversations view manually.

Here are the steps to fix:

1. Open any mail folder.
2. Choose the default view (Compact on my computer).
3. Manually change the view like you want, e.g. set the sort order, enable or disable the conversation view.
4. Click on View / Change View / Save Current View As a New View.
5. Name the view.
6. Choose "All Mail and Post folders" (or another option if you prefer).
7. Press OK.
8. Go back to step 1 and create a another view, do this for all of your commonly used views.

Now when you want to switch between views just switch to one of your newly created custom views. Be careful not to manually change anything while your custom view is enabled, if you do it will change the custom view's settings. If you want to change some view settings without changing your custom view's settings then switch back to the default view (Compact for me) and make the changes there.

Note that to make this more efficient I added the Change View button to the Quick Access Toolbar in the top left corner of the Outlook title bar. Now I'm only 2 clicks away from my most commonly accessed views.

Comment: Good suggestion. It would have made much more sense for Outlook not to save manual sorting permanently to a custom view.

Comment: Another tip is that the Custom Views get sorted alphabetically, so I prefix them with 1, 2, 3, etc to order them the way I want.